# The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.2.0-preview3-27014-02

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've upgraded the machine to the RTM release of .net core 2.2.100 for using preview 3. However I noticed that I was still referring to old versions in the SDK dependencies...

[image: Old version of SDK dependencies]

I realised had a global.json kicking around still specifying

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.100-preview3-009430"
  }
}
```

I changed it to:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.100"
  }
}
```

Then got the error:

> NETSDK1061: The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   version 2.2.0-preview3-27014-02, but with current settings, version
>   2.2.0 would be used instead. To resolve this issue, make sure the same settings are used for restore and for subsequent operations such as
>   build or publish. Typically this issue can occur if the
>   RuntimeIdentifier property is set during build or publish but not
>   during restore. For more information, see
>   https://aka.ms/dotnet-runtime-patch-selection.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.9.3

Answer (score 0):

This was Visual Studio caching the SDK version for the dependency resolution, a rebuild (clean build) didn't work, luckily simply restarting Visual Studio solved the problem.

Figured best to share this exact error message to save a poor sod burning time.